# Python code working differently after a print statement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to use regex to search the keys in a dict and return the matches.  The following code is simplified from the real code but shows the problem.

```
#!/bin/python

# Import standard Python modules
import os, sys, string, pdb, re

key=""
pat=""

steps = {"pcb":"xxx","aoi":"xxx","pcb-pec":"xxx","pcb_1":"xxx"}
pat = "pcb"

print"***Search the dict***"
for key in steps:
    print re.search(key,pat)

print"***Search the key***"
key = "pcb-pec"
pat = "pcb"
print re.search(key,pat)

print"***Search the key after printing it***"
key = "pcb-pec"
pat = "pcb"
print 'key:' + key+ ' ,pattern:' + pat
print re.search(pat,key)

exit()
```

And the output is this:

```
***Search the dict***
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000031FBC60>
None
None
None
***Search the key***
None
***Search the key after printing it***
key:pcb-pec ,pattern:pcb
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000031FBC60>
```

I don't understand why the pattern isn't found on the 3rd and 4th keys.

I don't understand why the pattern isn't found in the second test either.

I REALLY don't understand why it is found in the third test which is the same as the second, but with a print statement.

This is my first post, but I've learned a lot by searching and reading here.  Many thanks to you all.

Comment: `print re.search(pat, key)`

Comment: Sometimes you `re.search(key,pat)` and sometimes `re.search(pat,key)`

Answer (score 2):

The signature of `re.search` (given as [`re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)) takes the pattern first, then the string.

You should swap the order of the parameters:

```
re.search(pat, key)
#         ^^^^^^^^
```

And then the other keys will work:

```
In [27]: pat = "pcb"

In [28]: key = "pcb-pec"

In [29]: re.search(key,pat) # wrong order

In [30]: re.search(pat,key) # right order
Out[30]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='pcb'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You change the order of parameters in your last case. You have them out of order the first couple of times, and in the correct order the last time

```
re.search(pat,key)
```

is the correct order.

In the loop, you're getting a match the one time the pattern and the string happen to be the same.